# Trouble reading V_BG

Tags: analogread

I would like to read MUX 14 with the ADC.  On page 263 of the [Atmega328 data  sheet](http://www.atmel.com/Images/doc8161.pdf) it shows 1110b on the MUX corresponding with reading V_BG.

I need to read this so I can calibrate my sensor readings taken with the 5v reference to those taken with the 1.1v reference.  Because the 5v power supply may vary and the 1.1 is more stable, I need to be able to translate the readings taken with a 5v reference based on how the internal 1.1v is read.

Based on the [code for analogRead](http://garretlab.web.fc2.com/en/arduino/inside/arduino/wiring_analog.c/analogRead.html), I wrote this:

```
int readVBG(int _analogReference) {
  uint8_t low, high;
  ADMUX = (_analogReference << 6) | 14;
  sbi(ADCSRA, ADSC);
  while (bit_is_set(ADCSRA, ADSC));
  low  = ADCL;
  high = ADCH;
  return (high << 8) | low;
}
```

_analogReference is either 1 or 3 depending on the reference voltage desired.

I expect to read 1023 when _analogReference is 3 and about 225 when _analogReference is 1.  Instead I get smaller values which I'm guessing are from a floating (unconnected) analog pin.

Comment: How are you initializing ADCSRA?

Comment: As I understand it, these are registers on the atmega328.  If they were just variables, then the loop would never exit.

Comment: Ignacio, are you suggesting that I need to do more than twiddle a single bit in ADCSRA?

Comment: You might find this of interest: http://hacking.majenko.co.uk/making-accurate-adc-readings-on-arduino

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is that a 2ms delay is required after setting the ADMUX bits before starting the conversion.  Thank you Majenko for the link.

```
int readVBG(int _analogReference) {
  uint8_t low, high;
  ADMUX = (_analogReference << 6) | 14;
  delay(2); // Wait for voltage to settle
  sbi(ADCSRA, ADSC);
  while (bit_is_set(ADCSRA, ADSC));
  low  = ADCL;
  high = ADCH;
  return (high << 8) | low;
}
```

The above code is specifically for the Arduino UNO.  Majenko's link above has #ifdef statements which support other devices.

Comment: Can you accept this answer please so that StackExchange doesn't keep "bumping" it in the hope someone will give an accepted answer. :)